# Archive localResource in YARN : customize location

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I wanted to deploy a zip file as a local resource in `yarn`. Hence I did:

```
 packageResource.setResource(packageUrl);
    packageResource.setSize(packageFile.length());
    packageResource.setTimestamp(packageFile.lastModified());
    packageResource.setType(LocalResourceType.ARCHIVE);
    packageResource.setVisibility(LocalResourceVisibility.APPLICATION);
```

If my file name is `"abc.zip"`, Yarn unpacks all the zip contents into a folder called `"abc"`, not the current working directory.
For example, it creates something like:

```
 /grid/5/tmp/yarn-local/usercache/(user)/appcache/application_1394223910537_2533883/container_1394223910537_2533883_01_000002/abc
```

Can I customize this behavior? How do I get `Yarn` to unzip a file in the current working directory ,instead of creating a new directory?

The use-case is: if my app has some scripts, it would be useful to have all scripts deployed to current directory, instead of having to change the code to reference them from within the folder that Yarn creates.